# Can't Connect Elasticsearch in 9200 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

Even if a do a `sudo service elasticsearch start`, I'm not able to access `http://localhost:9200/`: `This site can’t be reached. localhost refused to connect.`

But when I hit elasticsearch status, I get:

```
● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; generated; vendor preset
 Active: active (exited) since Sat 2017-12-23 15:41:20 -03; 23min ag
   Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 29407 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop (code=exited,
Process: 29442 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exite

dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[29442]:  * Starting Elasticsearch Server
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[29442]:    ...done.
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
```

I already tried removing the comment char in `START_DAEMON`, and it seems it worked to a lot of people, as suggested here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730/11. I've tried too editing `elasticsearch.yml` file, explicitly setting network.host as `127.0.0.1` (or `0.0.0.0` as well) and http.port as `9200`. Also i tried mixing this solutions but none of them worked.

Also, after starting elasticsearch, `netstat -a -n | grep tcp | grep 9200` returns nothing.

If I hit `journalctl -u elasticsearch`, I get:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2017-12-23 12:31:03 -03, end at Sat 2017-12-23 16
dez 23 12:31:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 12:31:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[1449]:  * Starting
dez 23 12:31:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[1449]:    ...done.
dez 23 12:31:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 12:58:42 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 12:58:42 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[7235]:  * Stopping
dez 23 12:58:42 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[7235]:    ...done.
dez 23 12:58:42 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 12:58:42 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 12:58:42 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[7271]:  * Starting
dez 23 12:58:42 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[7271]:    ...done.
dez 23 12:58:42 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 12:59:34 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 12:59:34 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 12:59:34 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 12:59:34 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 13:24:49 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 13:24:49 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 13:33:24 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 13:33:24 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[16475]:  * Stoppin
dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[16475]:    ...done
dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[16511]:  * Startin
dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[16511]:    ...done
dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:04:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:04:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[19271]:  * Stoppin
dez 23 14:04:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[19271]:    ...done
dez 23 14:04:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:04:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:04:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[19306]:  * Startin
dez 23 14:04:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[19306]:    ...done
dez 23 14:04:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:06:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:06:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[19573]:  * Stoppin
dez 23 14:06:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[19573]:    ...done
dez 23 14:06:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:06:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:06:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[19609]:  * Startin
dez 23 14:06:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[19609]:    ...done
dez 23 14:06:11 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:11:39 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts

dez 23 14:11:39 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[20165]:  * Stoppin
dez 23 14:11:39 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[20165]:    ...done
dez 23 14:11:39 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:11:39 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:11:40 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[20200]:  * Startin
dez 23 14:11:40 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[20200]:    ...done
dez 23 14:11:40 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:14:07 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:14:07 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:14:07 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:14:07 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:25:03 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:25:03 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:25:03 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:25:03 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:26:29 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:26:29 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:26:29 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:26:29 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:26:58 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:26:58 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:26:58 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:26:58 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:27:06 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:27:06 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:27:06 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:27:06 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:31:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:31:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[23414]:  * Stoppin
dez 23 14:31:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[23414]:    ...done
dez 23 14:31:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 14:31:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 14:31:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[23449]:  * Startin
dez 23 14:31:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[23449]:    ...done
dez 23 14:31:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 15:09:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 15:09:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[26624]:  * Stoppin
dez 23 15:09:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[26624]:    ...done
dez 23 15:09:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 15:09:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 15:09:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[26661]:  * Startin
dez 23 15:09:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[26661]:    ...done
dez 23 15:09:59 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 15:35:13 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 15:35:13 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[28869]:  * Stoppin
dez 23 15:35:13 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[28869]:    ...done
dez 23 15:35:13 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 15:35:13 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 15:35:13 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[28904]:  * Startin
dez 23 15:35:13 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[28904]:    ...done
dez 23 15:35:13 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts 
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[29407]:  * Stoppin
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[29407]:    ...done
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Starts 
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[29442]:  * Startin
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[29442]:    ...done
dez 23 15:41:20 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts
```

Comment: Do you see any `.log` files in the folder `/var/log/elasticsearch/`? If you do, check if there are any errors/exceptions in the log files.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no .log inside `/var/log/elasticsearch/`, that actually is empty. I've looked for some other log file but couldn't find. The closest I found was just in status, in 
    `dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts`
    `dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[16511]:  * Startin`
    `dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 elasticsearch[16511]:    ...done`
    `dez 23 13:35:46 aleluia-Inspiron-5548 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts` 

wich seems to say that started fine.

Comment: Try `journalctl -u elasticsearch` to check if there are any errors/exceptions logged there.

Comment: There is only a bunch of things like `Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.` and `Stopping LSB: Starts elasticsearch...`, but any of them are errors/exceptions. I'm really running out of options right now.

Comment: Looks like some lines are truncated in the output you got from elasticsearch status command. Please do update the question. Also include the output you got from `journalctl -u elasticsearch` in the question, if there is any other information other than the information present in status command. Might help someone else trying to answer your question.

Comment: Did u use deb installation? And What is your ES version and did u use root permission to start your ES cluster?

Comment: Yes, used this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04
And yes, always use `sudo` to start, stop or restart ES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a question of incompatibility. Updating ES version solved the problem.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/connecting-elasticsearch-in-ubuntu-17-04/113085/5

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the web server, like if you are using apache2 , then restart it using 
`sudo service apache2 restart`
if you are using any other web server like nginx, change your host file and try to restart the webserver.

If this doesn't work, then check its your port is working fine or not, try to change it to 8080 or simply 80 , in .conf file. Just try this, if you face any problem, tell me.:)

Comment: I'm on a Ruby on Rails project, and in development environment, only using http://localhost:3000 as my server. Tried restarting as well but didn't worked. 

I tried changing from port 9200 to 8000. Actually, I tried setting `transport.tcp.port` and also `http.port`, in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` file. None worked. 
Is this yml file the one that you called .conf file? 

Thanks for helping me (: